# Type B NFC Chip in US Passport MRTD

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read a US Passport, issued 2010.  It has an NFC chip in it using type B modulation.  Most countries use Type A so I am just trying Type B now for the first time.

I am using an NXP PN532 NFC Controller.  I am using the inCommunicateThru instruction rather than the inDataExchange since I need to manually control the timeouts and error handling to successfully talk to a type B chip on this model NFC controller. I had to implement parts of the ISO-14443-4 protocol myself, such as the PCB, CID and CRC bytes, however it seems to work. I am able to select the application and request a challenge nonce from the tag.

The issue is that a lot of extra data is returned on top of the SW1 SW2 bytes, even when no return data is expected. For example, in response to a select MRTD application command (INS = 0xA4), there are many bytes returned:

Sending Type 4B Frame (PCB = 0A, CID = 01, CRC = 8A 2E)

-> 0A 01 00 A4 04 0C 07 A0 00 00 02 47 10 01 8A 2E

Type 4B Response Frame Received:

-> 0A 01 **62 36 82 01 38 83 02 00 11 85 01 00 84 07 A0 00 00 02 47 10 01 86 0D FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 8B 12 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF** 90 00

Then I try to get a challenge nonce by sending Type 4B Frame:

->0A 01 00 84 00 00 00 8E 3E

Note: For some reason I need to set Le to 00 for this to not give me a wrong length error

Type 4B Response Frame Received:

->0B 01 **90 9C 46 70 EC 02 BF FC 6E E2 A6 40 2D A5 0C 5F 93 02 B6 EB B5 61 1B BA** 90 00

The first two bytes are the PCB and the CID, and the last are the SW1 SW2, that I understand.

It is the bytes in **BOLD** that I cannot interpret.  Does anyone have any experience with US MRTDs or other Type B NFC chips that can help me interpret these bytes?  Is there a reference that I lack that can explain these extra bytes?

*****UPDATE 27-Nov-2014*******

Okay no, I wasn't crazy, the Get Challenge command is weird with this passport in that setting Le to 0x08 as per the ICAO spec yields a 6700 error, but with Le=0x00, too many bytes returned. Using inDataExchange (not inCommunicateThru) to get the challenge works (as in, I get 8 bytes).  This way I don't have to guess which 8 bytes are the challenge.

So great, now I with the challenge and the static public key in hand, I can execute the mutual authenticate instruction with the extended timeout mode and get the response bytes.  The INS is 0x82, P1,P2 = 0x00, Le,Lc=0x28

The result is that I get back a 0x00 from the PN532 (NFC controller), but no return bytes!  Not even SW1 or SW2.  Below is an example:

Sending Type 4B Frame: *0A 01* **00 82 00 00 28 73 3D 4E 2E C1 37 18 99 49 7C 4B 2A E0 79 A8 08 E2 6B 14 53 56 2C A4 66 D5 3E D8 94 56 79 50 2A 0D 6B C6 9A 75 5E B1 CB 28** *11 75*

Type 4B Response Frame Received: D5 43 00

The *ITALIC* bytes are the protocol bytes, the **BOLD** are the actual APDU

**Does anyone know what the idiosyncrasies are in the U.S MRTD Passport issued 2008-2010?**

Comment: Any chance you have a copy of the source code, perhaps downloaded before it disappeared?

Comment: UPDATE: @Papyrus, Some apps on Google Play can now decode US passports, when previously they couldn't. I don't know what happened. Perhaps, you are one of the guys who fixed it? In any case, here is a link to such an app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.imagedecoder (I have no idea if their code is open source, I'm just posting this comment to replace and amend my previous comment).

Comment: Perhaps it is a Waiting Time Extension request (WTX)?\

Answer (score 1):

In the first APDU response you probably get the FCP and FCI data back from the chip. This is weird because you explicitly told the application that you didn't want it (by specifying P2=`0C` in the SELECT by NAME APDU that you send).

What you get back is ASN.1 encoded, check the link [here](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#6236820138830200118501008407A0000002471001860DFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8B12FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF). The explanation of these bytes is in ISO/IEC 7816-4. You probably need to get that standard somehow.

As for the get challenge, you specify an Le with value `00`. This translates into an Ne with value 256. As Ne is the *maximum* size, you basically ask the eMRTD to return everything it can, up to 256 bytes. The 22 bytes you get (+`9000`) is civil, it could have returned the full 256 bytes. Usually you need a challenge of 8 bytes, so try Le set to `08` instead.

The good thing to notice is that this is all at the ISO/IEC 7816-4 level, so your ISO/IEC 14443 type B code is probably alright.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, yes you're correct, the extra bytes are the File Control Info (great link the the JS decoder, thanks!)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, it prompted me to review some of my hex dump traces and you're right, I was not sending the correct number of bytes due to a length error in my code.  I was sending 00 84 00 00 , hence the wrong length error!  I will clean this up and post the results