# Steps to make NFC ePassport APDU authentication work?

Tags: python, nfc, apdu

I'm working on a project where a mobile app has to communicate with ePassport via NFC. We have to pull out just the basic data about users like first and last name, DOB, photo, etc. After reading similar posts, reading the specs on [icao.int](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_v2_cons_en.pdf) and the code of the library [pyPassport](https://code.google.com/p/pypassport/), I'm still not sure what should be the first APDU command to be sent to ePassport. How to begin?

According to what I've read, it looks like it should be `get challenge` command `00 84 00 00 08` (somewhere is `B4` instead of `84`), but unfortunately I always get `63 00` response (no information given).

I know that before getting the data, I need to do the BAC. I saw the examples in the spec from above and I think I could code the BAC, but how to get to it? Does anybody know the flow/steps of how to begin and which authentification needs to be done (passive/active)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type B NFC Chip in US Passport MRTD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117183/type-b-nfc-chip-in-us-passport-mrtd)

Comment: ePassports from different countries may respond with different error codes, due to slight changes of standards. From what country is the ePassport you are trying to read?

Comment: It's EU passport. But the problem was that the NFC device we used was not compatible with ePassport. After changing the device it was ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you got 6300 response but I think it is because the epassport application is not yet selected. I could be wrong though.

BAC is the combination of GET CHALLENGE (`00 84 00 00 08`) and EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE commands. You only need BAC authentication in order to read basic passport holder info.

Here is the sequence of commands you need to send to read data from a passport:

1. Select - select the epassport application
2. Get Challenge
3. External Authenticate
4. Read Binary (protected by secure messaging) - read the DG1 file which contains basic passport holder info
5. Read Binary (protected by secure messaging) - read the DG2 file which contains the photo of the passport holder info

I can provide more details if needed. But for the meantime, you may also refer to ***ICAO Doc 9303, Machine Readable Travel Documents Part 3 Volume 2*** for BAC specifications.

Comment: Thanks Chooch, that's the answer I was looking for. Also here's the document I find http://www.iom.int/seguridad-fronteriza/lit/icao/supplementtoicaodoc9303-release7.pdf with the steps starting from the page 17. The reason for getting the 6300 response was that we used external NFC reader which was not comaptible with the ePassport.